# Same tax rate for multiple countries

Tags: configuration, tax

How can I set up the same tax rate for multiple countries without making an entry in the tax_rates.csv file for every country? Is there an easy way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

According to my information you can't. For every country that needs a tax rate > 0, you'll need a new row.
If you search on Google you'll find some pre-pepared .csv files with all the country-codes you need.

### Some that I found:

https://www.yireo.com/blog/1722-new-eu-tax-rates-for-your-magento-shop
https://www.phpro.be/news/list-countries-magento-including-magento-country-code